# Generalize TensorflowGANS from grayscale to RGB

Tags: tensorflow, generator, generative-adversarial-network

I am writing a tensorflow based GAN script.
It was for grayscale images but I cannot make the generator works for RGB
which in my code is represented by 
dim =3
I can imagine I do have to update also the other layers adding the third dimension, but how do I do it at the Dense layer?

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense( (IMG_SIZE//4) * (IMG_SIZE//4) *256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

model.add(layers.Reshape((IMG_SIZE//4, IMG_SIZE//4, 256)))
assert model.output_shape == (None, IMG_SIZE//4, IMG_SIZE//4, 256) # Note: None is the batch size

model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
assert model.output_shape == (None, IMG_SIZE//4, IMG_SIZE//4, 128)
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
assert model.output_shape == (None, IMG_SIZE//2, IMG_SIZE//2, 64)
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
assert model.output_shape == (None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, dim)

return model
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too vauge, I am posting anothe question, as I cannot understand how to delete this one